# Determine why ResourceManager.GetObject returns null?

Tags: c#, image

I'm working in C# and I am a bit rusty. The following code returns `null` for the image I am trying to load into a `pictureBox`:

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = MyProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;
Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(image_name);
```

There are no exceptions or other indications of a problem. The image was added through the resource manager, and `image_name` is valid.

How can I determine why `GetObject` is returning `null`?

Comment: image_name is not valid.  No point in writing code like that when you can use the Properties class to do this, it has a typesafe property getter for the image and you can't get the image name wrong.

Comment: Thanks Hans. How can it be trouble-shot? Is there a resource browser so we can see the names of resources? Sorry to have to ask. Apparently, Visual Studio is not using the name of the asset that was added through the resource manager.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Bitmap myImage = MyProject.Properties.Resources.image_name;
```